# Circular dependency involving Observer design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I am working on a multi-layered project that involves a server and some clients.

Most of the messages are initiated by the client and sent to the server, meaning they look like this: 
Client -> Intermediate Layers -> Server

But some messages are server-initiated updates, meaning they're reversed.
So I need to implement the Observer pattern, where the client is the Observer and the server is the Subject. The problem is that the client already has a reference to the server through the intermediate layers. This means that I can't let the server have a reference to the client (again through the intermediate layers), because then I would have circular dependency.

How do I solve this issue? One idea that I've read about is using a mediator like this:
Server -> Mediator
Client -> Mediator

But I've failed to understand how to make it work.

Comment: Why does the client have a dependency on the server rather than on the intermediate layer?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear - the client has a dependency on the intermediate layer, but it still "knows" the server because the intermediate layer depends on the server

Comment: In the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) the `Subject` does not have a dependency on the `ConcreteObserver` (in your case the `Client`) only on the `Observer` interface.

Comment: @ChrisDrew thank you very much, that pretty much solved my problem :)